# Is there a way to apply K-Means to the output of Conv/Dense layers in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have trained a CNN on Fashion MNIST data with the following configuration:
Conv-Pool-Dropout-Conv-Pool-Dropout-Flat-Dense-Dropout-Output
I would like to change the configuration to: 
Conv-Clustering-Pool-Dropout-Conv-Clustering-Pool-Dropout-Flat-Dense-Clustering-Dropout-Output
However, I want this new configuration only for testing and not training the model (I can use the weights from the trained model and set them for the model with Clustering configuration). Is there a way to add the Clustering layer using tensorflow? 
I would like to represent the output of the Conv and Dense layers using the cluster centroids to examine the effects on the accuracy of the model.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is in fact two questions:

1. How can I apply an operation only in some config and not others?
2. How can I apply k-means?

And here are the answers:

1. To apply an operation based on the value of some tensorflow variable `do_clustering` you can use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) with:

   ```
   maybe_clustered_ouput = tf.cond(do_clustering,
                                   lambda: my_clustering_operation(input),
                                   lambda: input)
   ```
2. To apply k-means clustering, you can use [`tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/experimental/KMeans<code>) (and replace that instead ofmy_clustering_operation` in the above snippet)

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried something like this:
conv1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='Conv1')(inputs) 
Test = Lambda(k_means_activations, name='Test_Layer')(conv1)
where k_means_activation is a function for using tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.KMeans. However, I get the error:
ValueError: Tensor("Test_Layer/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Equal:0", shape=(), dtype=bool).
I did not use this model for training but only testing using weights from a trained model. Is this error obvious?

Comment: Avoid using Lambda this way, as AFAIK this is not how it's supposed to be used (according to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda it's supposed to receive a function as the first argument, not an activation layer). Try doing something more resembling the snippet I suggested?

Comment: I should clarify that k_means_activations is a function where I used the KMeans estimator. However, I will try exactly what you have proposed. Thanks once again.